# Web Push notification using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, websocket, push-notification

Hi I am using websockets to get the data from server and succesfully getting data and data is updating,whenever there is a change in data in backend iam unable to know data is updated or not for that i am trying the below code. But not getting any notifiaction popup kind of thing

Got the Popup to allow notification and permission is granted.

```
const URL = "ws://localhost:8000";
 useWebSocket(URL, {
    onOpen: () => {
      // console.log('WebSocket connection established.');
    },
    onMessage: (event) => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(event.data),"event");
      setAllOrdersData(JSON.parse(event?.data));
      clearFilter(); 
      if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
        const notification = new Notification('New message', {
          body: "new Message",
          data:"test",
        });
        notification.onclick = () => {
          window.focus();
        };
      }

    },
  });
```

In Edge i am getting but in chrome unable to get